# AJAX/Code Igniter throws parsererror, method not called

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am currently trying to debug a Code Igniter (3) method. I have a method called `sync` which synchronises (saves) form data in the database. It is called using jQuery/AJAX. After clicking the submit button, it returns an XHR with status code 200 (and an empty response text) -- indicating that the call itself seemed to be successful, but it still throws a parsererror. I placed some `log_message()` flags to find out where the method seems to crash:

```
    public function sync(){
    $i = 0;

    log_message('debug',"Flag ".$i);
    $i++;
    // ... Steps in between, etc.
```

But the logging system does not register anything, indicating that the sync method is seemingly not even called. I am sure the submitted path in the AJAX-call is correct:

```
$("#sync-btn").click(function(){
    var form = $("#annotation-sync");

    var submit_form_data = form.serialize();
    console.log(submit_form_data);
    $.ajax({
        type :'POST',
        url : "http://localhost/Project/"+"index.php/annotate/sync",
        data : submit_form_data,
        dataType: 'json',
            encode : 'true',
            beforeSend: function(){
            timeout = setTimeout(function(){
                form.find(".load").fadeIn();
                }, 1000);
            },
            success: function(res) {
                console.log(res);
                $(".navbar-header button").prop("disabled",true);


            },
            error: function(jqXHR, errorThrown) {
                console.log('jqXHR:');
                console.log(jqXHR);
                console.log('errorThrown:');
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        })
```

Does anyone know how to debug this kind of error?

Comment: is your bage refreshing?

Comment: @madalinivascu No, it's not. It's not supposed to, either.

Comment: you can't have a parse error and return a 200 response,usually you get a 500 error,did you enable error reporting

Comment: @madalinivascu Thanks, I figured it out. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is appropriate given the short lifespan of this question. I found out what the problem was:

```
$route["annotate/(:any)"] = "annotate";
```

Apparently, the call would be redirected, so `"annotate/sync"` was redirected to simply `"annotate/"`. I guess I have to read more into CodeIgniter's routing.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove dataType: 'json' because its not responding any json data as i see. also check url properly given or not